# Sorting 2d points by the distance from the origin

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need to write a c code which sorts a random number of 2d points from the point that is the closest
to the origin to the point that has the biggest distance from the origin.Since I need to have a time complexity of n*log(n) where n is the number of points we get from the user Im thinking of using the heap sort method.The only problem is finding the closest pair to the distance by the equation of the distance between (x,y and (0,0) that is sqrt((x^2)+(y^2) and implementing this equation to the sorting method that I use.Just looking for some hints or any suggestions for how do I continue from here so I will appreciate any 
piece of advice

Comment: What´s the problem? Take any sorting function, and at that code parts where two elements/points are compared, calculate both distances and take the point with lower distacne first.

Answer (score 1):

Any good comparison sort algorithm will run in O(n log n). For efficiency you want the comparator to run as fast as possible. One thought: compare `x^2+y^2` rather than the actual distance. Another: calculate that quantity just once for each point and cache it in the point object or elsewhere, rather than recalculating for each comparison.

Answer (score 0):

**Heap sort Solution:**

1.Create a max heap of distance of each point from origin.

2.suppose if you are implementing heap by array then just create   one more dummy array which will contain index of that point.

3.just apply  normal heap sort & when you are doing swapping between indexes then also swap same index in dummy array.

```
lets say my input from user is following point    
1,0 
8,6  
4,4
6,0
```

so my distance array will contain distance

```
1,10,sqrt(32),6
```

my dummy  array will contain normal index of each point

```
1,2,3,4
```

now create a max heap after crating it your array will be
    `10,6,sqrt(32),1` 
 so at that time your dummy array will look like
    `2,4,3,1`.
 now apply heap sort 10 will swap with 1 as well as 2 will
 be swap with 1 in dummy array & so on......

By this in dummy array you will get all index of point which is nearest from origin to farest  from origin

tell me if there is anything which is you don't understood.

Comment: What does the term 'max heap' mean?

Comment: heap in which parent  element is always greater than  its child

Comment: i think you know there is two kind of heap one is heap in which parent is always less than child which is known as min heap & other one is parent is greater than child which is known as max heap.

Comment: binary heap:  http://geeksquiz.com/binary-heap/   Heap sort:http://geeksquiz.com/heap-sort/